# Update no banco de dados Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Preciso alterar apenas o campo do comentario de um contato. Mas quando tento alterar este campo acusa este erro `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Client'`. Gostaria de saber o porque, já que a função de update passa o id do contato.

Função do model para o update do comentario:

```
  updateComents(Client id) async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.update("Contatos", id.toJson(),
        where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id.id]);
    return res;
  }
```

Função do select no banco:

```
  Future<List> getRows() async{

    final db = await database;

    var res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Contatos ORDER BY fullname");

    return res.toList();

  }
```

contactsList é atribuido ao getRows: `contactsList = await getRows();`

Botão aonde chamo esta função:

```
child: CupertinoButton(
       onPressed: (){
           model.updateComents(model.contactsList[index]["id"]);
            },
            child: Text("Salvar Alterações")

       ),
```

Sou novato com dart/flutter com banco de dados.

Comment: Qual o tipo dessa lista `model.contactsList`?

Comment: É uma variável atribuída a uma consulta no banco que ordena pelo nome.

Comment: Então mas qual o tipo da lista? Por exemplo, é uma lista desse tipo `List<Client>`? Porque se for tu poderia fazer assim no botão `model.updateComents(model.contactsList[index]` sem colocar o `["id"]`

Comment: Ah sim é uma `Future<List>`

Comment: Teste da forma que sugeri no comentário acima, se der certo crio uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: Ainda não agora retorna o erro `type 'QueryRow' is not a subtype of type 'Client'`

Comment: Sem saber o tipo correto da lista e o que é recebido nela fica meio difícil... EDITE a sua pergunta e coloca como tu faz para alimentar essa lista e quais os dados ela recebe. E especifique o tipo dela, por exemplo `Future<List<TipoTal>>`

Comment: Debugue seu projeto também e nos diga se o erro ocorre no click do botão ou dentro do método `updateComents`

Comment: Vou verificar o que pediu, esta meio confuso pois não foi eu quem criou o código então até entender estou um pouco perdido também.

Comment: O problema é que você está passando um `int` pra uma função que espera um `Client`. Provavelmente o correto seria chamar como sugerido pelo @MatheusRibeiro: `model.contactsList[index]`.

Comment: Sim, ja passei somente o `model.contactsList[index]` e retornou o erro `type 'QueryRow' is not a subtype of type 'Client'`

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro fiz a edição, ficou mais claro desta forma ?

Comment: Sim, assim que possível eu crio uma resposta.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Na sua classe `Client` crie o seguinte método

```
void fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id: json["id"];
    fullname: json["fullname"];
}
```

*Obs.: Utilizei dois campos como exemplo apenas, implemente os outros*

Modifique o click do seu `CupertinoButton` para

```
child: CupertinoButton(
  onPressed: (){
    Client client = Client().fromMap(model.contactsList[index]);
    model.updateComents(client);
  },
  child: Text("Salvar Alterações")
)
```

Caso não de certo faça

```
child: CupertinoButton(
  onPressed: (){
    Client client = Client();
    client.fromMap(model.contactsList[index]);
    model.updateComents(client);
  },
  child: Text("Salvar Alterações")
)
```

*Obs.: Estou sem Flutter no momento para fazer o teste completo*

**Explicação**

O método `rawQuery` retorna para nós um `Map<String, dynamic>` então para você chamar o `updateComents` você precisa pegar o registro em questão e transformar em um objeto `Client` para ai sim poder passar como parâmetro do teu método.

Você pode dar uma olhada neste link para um exemplo muito mais completo [Using SQLite in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-sqlite-in-flutter-187c1a82e8b)

Comment: Entendi, apenas mais uma duvida que acabei esquecendo de comentar, como pegaria o valor do campo que o usuario digitar que no meu caso é `final controllerComent = TextEditingController(); ` ?

Comment: @MarceloLemos7 vincula o controller no teu TextEdit e depois pra pegar os dados faça `var textoDigitado = controllerComent.Text`. Aconselho você dar uma lida nos documentos do Flutter para aprender algumas coisinhas básicas.